# Uncaught (in promise) JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, promise, try-catch

The following section of code produces an error if it is given a bad input:

> Uncaught (in promise) error

```js
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  $("#modal-submit").on("click", function(e) {
    resolve($("#modal-input").val());
  })
})
```

I've tried adding a `catch()` method to the promise but have had no luck catching the error. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```js
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  $("#modal-submit").on("click", function(e) {
    resolve($("#modal-input").val());
  })
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: What is 'bad input'? Your code works fine when implemented: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/y3w0j5xb/. We need a more detailed explanation of the problem and code sample to be able to help you

Comment: Based on what you have written here, it seems likely the exception is being thrown elsewhere in your code, in whatever function is consuming the promise you are constructing here. Which would be why adding a catch statement here is not doing anything.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think the error may actually be in another part of my code. I had assumed it was with this promise as it was working before I wrote this one. Thanks again!